# <a> element does not recognize the file extension automatically when downloading a file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm currently developing an application where the user clicks on an element, that element calls a JS function and the function handles a file download.

The files are reports generated dynamically by [Devexpress XtraReports module](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos/), converted to Base64 and then sent back to the client side. When the client receives the Base64 string, the JS function creates an `<a>` element, sets the **href** attribute to `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNCiWio[...]` and simulates a click with the `click()` event.

Here's the piece of JS code that handles the file download:

```
let downloadLink;

    try {
        downloadLink = executionId ? await getLinkPdfBase64(executionId) : false;
    } catch (error) {
        downloadLink = false;
        console.log(error);
    }

    if (downloadLink) {
        const aElement = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink = "data:application/pdf;base64," + downloadLink;
        aElement.setAttribute("download", currentReportData.LayoutName);
        aElement.setAttribute("href", downloadLink);
        aElement.click();
        aElement.remove();
    } else {
        DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert( //Ignore this, it's a Devexpress component
            "Your report could not be generated",
            "Alert"
        );
    }
```

**The problem is:**

When I generate a report with custom parameter types, Devexpress generates it correctly (the Base64, if converted to string, is visibly correctly formed) but the browser (Google Chrome) downloads the file with the extension **".0"**.

If the report has normal Devexpress parameters (like Strings, Int32, Guids, etc)) the file is downloaded with the correct **".pdf"** extension.

Here's a picture of a correctly downloaded PDF and a ".0" extension file:

[image: Example Error Picture]

Could it be the JS function the cause or the solution to the problem? If not, almost for sure there will be something wrong with the report generator (Devexpress).

> NB: If I manually change the ".0" extension to ".pdf" the file opens and it is displayed / formed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I ended up solving it just by adding the file extension **".pdf"** in the `download` attribute, so when the browser can't recognize it, you are already specifying which one it is:

```
aElement.setAttribute("download", currentReportData.LayoutName + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Does this one override the ".0" extension or concat it like ".0.pdf" ?

Comment: @cengizsevimli it overrides the extension, so if you have a file like "file.0" you will end up having "file.pdf"